# How can I add a modal for each image of my gallery?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how can I have a modal for each image when I click the images.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/josemon322/pen/OJoyYgK?editors=1010)

Javascript

```
function showImages() {
  while(gallery.firstChild) gallery.removeChild(gallery.firstChild)
  
  var offset = (page - 1) * perPage;
  var dots = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-dot');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++){
    dots[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  
  dots[page - 1].classList.add('active');
  
  for (var i = offset; i < offset + perPage; i++) {
    if ( images[i] ) {
      var template = document.createElement('div');
      var title = document.createElement('p');
      var titleText = document.createTextNode(images[i].title);
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      
      template.classList.add('template')
      img.setAttribute("src", images[i].source);
      img.setAttribute('alt', images[i].title);

      title.appendChild(titleText);
      template.appendChild(img);
      template.appendChild(title);
      gallery.appendChild(template);      
    }
  }
  
  // Animate images
  var galleryItems = document.querySelectorAll('.template')
  for (var i = 0; i < galleryItems.length; i++) {
    var onAnimateItemIn = animateItemIn(i);
    setTimeout(onAnimateItemIn, i * 100);
  }
  
  function animateItemIn(i) {
    var item = galleryItems[i];
    return function() {
      item.classList.add('animate');
    }
  }
  
  // Update page indicator
  pageIndicator.textContent = "Page " + page + " of " + pages;
  
}

showImages();
```

I have been doing it pretty easily using images inside divs and displaying them from my html file but now that I manage to create the images from the javascript file I can't find a simple way to add modals to each image.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that takes the imageURL as a parameter and creates a modal. and then make that an onClick for each image item.

```
template.onclick = () => showModal(images[i].source)
```

and the function will look a bit like this:

```
function showModal(url) {
  document.body.appendChild(modal(url))
}
```